# Quasar2 Vue3 Cypress q-popup-edit

Tags: popup, cypress, vuejs3, quasar-framework, editbox

I have the following vue template:

```
<template>
  <q-item tag="label" v-ripple>
    <q-popup-edit
      v-model="model"
      :cover="false"
      fit
      buttons
      :validate="validate"
      @before-show="modelProxy = model"
    >
      <template v-slot:title>
        <div class="text-mono">
          {{ name }}
        </div>
      </template>
      <q-input
        color="indigo"
        v-model="modelProxy"
        dense
        autofocus
        counter
        :type="dataType ? dataType : 'text'"
        :hint="hint"
        :error="error"
        :error-message="errorMessage"
      />
    </q-popup-edit>
    <q-item-section>
      <q-item-label class="text-mono">{{ name }}</q-item-label>
      <q-item-label v-if="offset && model && model.length > offset" caption
        >...{{
          model.substring(model.length - offset, model.length)
        }}</q-item-label
      >
      <q-item-label v-else caption>{{ model }}</q-item-label>
    </q-item-section>
  </q-item>
</template>
```

I would like to perform E2E test using Cypress with the following code snippet:

```
  it('Verify Edit Box from auto-generated page', () => {
    cy.get('[data-test="popup-edit-setting-1"]').contains("Auto Generated Edit box");
    cy.get('[data-test="popup-edit-setting-2"]').contains("Auto Generated Edit box (Number)");
    cy.get('[data-test="popup-edit-setting-1"]').should("be.enabled"); // XXX
    cy.get('[data-test="popup-edit-setting-1"]').focus().click().type("Hello");//.click("SET");
    cy.get('[data-test="popup-edit-setting-1"]').find("label").should('have.value', 'Hello') // XXX
   });
```

It stumbles on the `XXX` points.
@Fody's solution works but there is one minor issue. I have 2 popup edit box. One with normal string, another with only numeric. There are 2 test cases for the numeric popup editbox. One with invalid normal string entry and another with valid numbers. The problem is that at the end of the test, the numeric popup edit box does NOT return to display mode. It stays popup.

[image]

Comment: Where is `data-test` attribute added to source?

Comment: It's in  `src/components/AutoGenerate/AutoGenerate.vue`

Comment: I thought it might be - but you only show the template above - to make the question make sense you want to show the parent template where the attribute is added.

Comment: It will only complicate the question unncessarily if it is only for this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would test q-popup-edit. I used a generic example, yours may differ in some details.

I aimed to test based on what a user sees rather than any internal class or internal properties.

The user story is:

- the text to be edited has a "hand" pointer when hovered
- click on it to change it from "display" mode to "edit" mode
- the input is automatically focused, user can start typing
- user enters some text
- user clicks away and the input loses focus, goes back to "display" mode

```js
// activate popup editor
const initialText = 'Click me'
cy.contains('div.cursor-pointer', initialText)    // displayed initial text 
  .should('be.visible')                           // with hand cursor
  .click()

// initial condition
cy.focused()                                // after click <input> should have focus
  .as('input')                              // save a reference
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName', 'INPUT')  // verify it is the input
cy.get('@input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', initialText)                // displayed text is also in the input
cy.contains('8').should('be.visible')       // character count

// edit action
cy.get('@input')                           
  .clear()
  .type('test input')
cy.get('@input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'test input')              // verify input  

cy.contains('10').should('be.visible')     // character count has changed

// back to display mode
cy.get('body').click()                     // go back to display mode

cy.contains('div.cursor-pointer', 'test input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('contain', 'test input')            // verify display element
cy.contains('10').should('not.exist')      // edit counter has gone
```

**Notes**

To start the edit, you need to identify the display-mode element. It's easiest if you have some unique text in the field, so try to arrange that in the page initial data.

If no unique text, look for a label or some other selectable element nearby then navigate to it.

If you add a `data-cy` attribute to the `<q-popup-edit>`, it will not exist in the DOM until the component enters edit-mode (so you can't use it in the initial click()).

Comment: Bravo! This works! However, there is one minor issue. I have 2 popup edit box. One with normal string, another with only numeric. There are 2 test cases for the numeric popup editbox. One with invalid normal string entry and another with valid numbers. The problem is that at the end of the test, the numeric popup edit box does NOT return to display mode. It stays popup. Screen shot in my OP.

Comment: I'll check it out with a numeric edit as well...